# Neo4J BatchInserter progressive slowdown. 2.0 M6

Tags: java, neo4j, batch-processing

I am observing a crippling slowdown during the use of BatchInserter and would appreciate a help or confirmation (so I will know if neo4J is a viable option).

Config data below.

Basically we are evaluating use of Neo4J for our linking project, I have prepared files with conusmers, addresses and their homes and county documents.

The sizes are around 200M - 400M each.

It started good.

Load of consumers 216M without index - 1 M per 5 sec with 2 Lucene indexes 1M per 15 sec.

Next step slowdown was noticed, but I attributed it to double number of properties on Address
Load of address file 170M without index - 1M per 15 sec.

Next slowdown was very obvious, even creating BatchInserter on database took 10 minutes were before it was instant.

Load of consumer to address relationship 350M - 1M per 70 sec and progressively slow shutdown times like hours.

Now it is getting even worse. 150M homes- first 1M took 1000 seconds, now though after 10M it's down to 100sec for 1M records (home has only 3 properties).

1. Why is it slowing down for what is basically appending entities to database, never seen it in any other database implementation, unless indexes were involved. Is it possible that my manually created indexes became auto?

   ```
     BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider(inserter);
     BatchInserterIndex iNames = indexProvider.nodeIndex("Names", MapUtil.stringMap("type","exact"));
     ...
     for(String name : fullNames) {
               iNames.add(node,MapUtil.map("names",name));
     }
     ...
      indexProvider.shutdown();
      inserter.shutdown();
   ```
2. I used the settings from a previous thread on slow relaltionships insert. Is there anything else that can be set on machine or program.

I am not very profecient with Java, specifically Jvm settings and environment. So when it comes to runtime be gentle in your explanations.

The server is Windows 2008
256GB of ram and 42 2.8 cores (AMD).
The drive is not enterprise level, but fast enough.
Neo4j in Milestone 6 version 2.0
And the batch load is written in Java. JDK 7

P.S. Not related, but anybody knows why I couldn't post this to Google group Neo4j, tried like 3 times.

Comment: Do you use the jvm with the default settings for the garbage collector ?

Comment: The above numbers were ran with defaults. (No switches)

Comment: I suspect that it is slowing down because the java garbage collector hits the limit of the available heap space. You should try to run java with the following option "-verbose:gc" to see if the GC is full and how often does it stop because of that. You can try to allocate more heap space with the following option "-Xms10g" where you can replace the 10 by a larger number to see if it speeds things a bit.